# Behave BDD reusing steps from common step file

Tags: python-behave

How do i re use steps from common_step.py
example:

**common_feature:**

Given log in with "abc" user

**common_step:**

@given('log in with "{user}" user')

**anotherFile_feature**

Given log in with "xyz" user

**anotherFile_steps:**

how do i pass that xyz user in here, can i get an example

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you need to reuse your user in another steps or parts of your code, shouldn't you just assign the value of the user to a variable?

```
@given('log in with "{user}" user')
def do_login(context, user)
    context.user = user  # the context variable will be accessible during execution time
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend that you post more documented questions, as it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

As [@herickmota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13234986/herickmota) says, if you want to share values between different functions in your code you should use the **context** variable, which is shared by all the steps during the execution of the test, and in which you can store as many values as you want to be able to retrieve them wherever you want.

If, on the other hand, what you want is to call from a step to another step that you have already defined, you should use the **context.execute_steps** method, of which you have the documentation at https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?=execute_steps#behave.runner.Context.execute_steps and you can see an example at https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial08.html.

I'll give you some examples:

[image: Directory_tree_1]

This is the example of a valid directory tree. You must have the *.feature files inside a directory named "features" and also inside that directory you must have de "steps" directory with the steps definitions inside.

[image: Directory_tree_invalid]

The second directory tree is an **invalid** directory tree, because the anohter_file_feature.feature file is unable to find the step definitions. In any case, I can't find any situation where you should separate the features in this way.

[image: Last_Directory_Tree_Example]

The last of the directory trees is the most commonly used sort, as it allows you to separate features into folders according to the criteria you see fit. This is the structure I would recommend to organise your Behave files.

Once we are clear about the valid distributions of the files in different folders, let's talk about how to call the methods from the different *.feature files.

To begin with, the first Scenario we have as an example would be the `features/common_features/common_feature.feature`, in which we make the most typical call to a step to which we pass a parameter, in this case the name "Manuel".

```
Feature: Common_feature

  Scenario: Scenario number one
    Given log in with "Manuel" user
```

The definition of the step is in the file `features/steps/common_step.py`

```
from behave import *


@given(u'log in with "{user}" user')
def step_impl(context, user):
    print("I'm logging with the user: " + user)
```

The output if we run de command `behave features/common_features/common_feature.feature` is:

```
$ behave features/common_features/common_feature.feature
Feature: Common_feature # features/common_features/common_feature.feature:1

  Scenario: Scenario number one     # features/common_features/common_feature.feature:3
    Given log in with "Manuel" user # features/steps/common_step.py:4

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 step passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.001s
```

In another path, we have the file `features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature` in which we have defined the following two examples: one invoking again the step we already had declared in `features/steps/common_step.py` and another with a new step, which implicitly calls the step `log in with "{user}" user`:

```
Feature: Common_feature

  Scenario: Scenario number two
    Given log in with "José" user


  Scenario: Scenario number three
    Given calling indirectly with "Antonio" user
```

The definitions of the step we have in `features/steps/another_file_steps.py` is as follows:

```
from behave import *


@given(u'calling indirectly with {user} user')
def step_impl(context, user):
    context.execute_steps("Given log in with " + user + " user")
```

And the output of running the command `behave features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature` is:

```
$ behave features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature
Feature: Common_feature # features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature:1

  Scenario: Scenario number two   # features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature:3
    Given log in with "José" user # features/steps/common_step.py:4

  Scenario: Scenario number three                # features/another_features/another_file_feature.feature:7
    Given calling indirectly with "Antonio" user # features/steps/another_file_steps.py:4

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.006s
```

As you can see, here are some basic examples of the file structure in Behave and how to call both directly and indirectly to the steps from the features.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, i was looking more for the solution for reusing the step from a different step file, i will try to give another example.

Comment: lets say i have feature_file1 with Given change the configuration to "proceed" and the step_file1 has the step defined for it, now i need to create another feature file feature_file2 in a different directory and that directory has its step_file2 now in feature_file2 i have how do i reuse Given change the configuration to "skip" (instead of duplication the step in step_file2 how do i use the step from the step_file1 with passing that "skip" parameter ) example u provided is for reusing the step of the same feature file. in my case two feature files in a different directories.

Comment: In any case, I'll give you an example in my answer and let's see if it helps to you